# jQuery Flot - Force axis values

Tags: jquery, mysql, flot

I'm trying to display website hits with jQuery flot.
The problem: There aren't hits on any day.
Example (for a week): 
Monday - 2
Tuesday - 12
Wednesday - 0
.....
Sunday - 0

I get the data from my database with the following statement:

```
var pageviews = [
            <?php                               
                $query = "SELECT DAY(`h_date`) AS day, COUNT(*) as zugriffe FROM hits WHERE h_server = $serverID AND WEEK(`h_date`,3) = '$selectKW' GROUP BY day";

                $mydb->query($query);
                $wCount = 0;
                while ($row = $mydb->fetchRow()){
                    $wCount++;
                    echo '['.$row['day'].','.$row['zugriffe'].'],';
                    $tag = $row['day'];
                }
            ?>

        ];
```

Sample output database:

```
day zugriffe
13  0
14  133
15  114
16  0
17  86
19  1
```

How can I fill up the missing axis values for the days with 0 hits?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create the array of days first and then fill in the values (from database or zero).

Comment: Samle Output from database: day zugriffe
13 93
14 133
15 0
16 116
17 86
19 0

Answer (score 1):

You can just fix your data before giving it to flot.

For example, give database output like:

```
// this is unsorted and missing days 12, 13, 18, 19, 20
var pageviews = [[14,0],[11,133],[16,0],[17,89],[21,1]];

// sort it just in case (not sure if this is applicable to your data)
// sorting on X value
pageviews.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[0]-b[0];
});

// a quick function to scan and fill in missing x values
$.map(pageviews, function(obj){
    var rV = [];
    if (this.lastVal){
        var x = obj[0];
        var lastX = this.lastVal[0];
        for (var i = lastX + 1; i < x; i++){
            rV.push([i,0]);
        }
        rV.push(obj);
    } else {        
        rV = [obj];
    }
    this.lastVal = obj;
    return rV;
});
```